# How does the code to drop privileges that is shown in perlsec actually work?

Tags: linux, perl, userid, groupid

In [perlsec](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec#Cleaning-Up-Your-Path), there is the following code that drops privileges (the line numbers have been added by me):

```
 1  my @temp     = ($EUID, $EGID);
 2  my $orig_uid = $UID;
 3  my $orig_gid = $GID;
 4  $EUID = $UID;
 5  $EGID = $GID;
 6  # Drop privileges
 7  $UID  = $orig_uid;
 8  $GID  = $orig_gid;
 9  # Make sure privs are really gone
10  ($EUID, $EGID) = @temp;
11  die "Can't drop privileges"
12      unless $UID == $EUID  && $GID eq $EGID;
13  $ENV{PATH} = "/bin:/usr/bin"; # Minimal PATH.
14  # Consider sanitizing the environment even more.
15  exec 'myprog', 'arg1', 'arg2'
16      or die "can't exec myprog: $!";
```

I thought that I had understood the concept of real user ids, effective user ids and saved user ids, but I admit that I have no chance to understand this code. [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$REAL_GROUP_ID) has explanations about `$GID`, `$EGID`, `$UID` and `$EUID` and states that it uses a system call to alter them, but does not state which system call that is; this might be part of my problem.

Could somebody please explain what happens there?

Notably, lines `7` and `8` don't make any sense, unless lines `4` and `5` change the values of `$UID` and `$GID`. But as far as I have understood from perlvar, the latter should not be the case. Rather, perlvar explicitly states:

> You can change both the real gid and the effective gid at the same time by using POSIX::setgid().

This citation is from the section about `$GID`, but there are similar statements in the sections about `$UID`, `$EGID` and `$EUID`. Since the sample code uses simple assignments instead of those POSIX functions, I strongly assume that lines `4` and `5` change only `$EUID` and `EGID`, not `$UID` or `$GID`. Given that, what are the lines `7` and `8` needed for?

If I would be able to understand this, I guess I could understand the rest of the code as well.

If somebody takes the time, it would probably be sufficient to focus on `$UID` and `$EUID`. I also have understood that we should clean the environment etc. and how we should call `exec`. So it's "only" the (E)UID/(E)GID assignments that I don't understand.

Finally, I am convinced that this is not a duplicate question:

There are several (seemingly) similar questions about Perl and effective and real user ids on this site, but they are "How do I drop privileges"-questions. None of these questions neither the answers to them mention the pattern from the code above. Rather, the code in the answers consists of one or two lines of Perl, or the answers simply recommend using modules (e.g., `Privileges::Drop`).

In contrast, I specifically would like to understand how the pattern above works and why it is necessary at all, given that the answers to respective other questions on this site make the impression that it's quite trivial to achieve the same task.

Comment: Have you added in some `echo` statements to trace through this?

Comment: Not yet, because I even don't know how I should set up a test case that's suitable to learn from it. If I do it wrong, I'll probably come to the wrong conclusions. Probably my script should be setgid / setuid to test it, correct?

Comment: Re "*I even don't know how I should set up a test case*", You need a setuid/setgid script, which is a script that's executed as its owner instead of as the person that launched it. This is done using `chmod`.

Comment: Since that code doesn't DO anything (you can comment out lines 15 and 16), it's a perfect test case.  Add in some prints, do `chmod u+s g+s` to set the suid bits, and see what happens.

Comment: Testing this turned out to be surprisingly hard. I have set the script suid-root / sgid-root, have logged into the machine as an unprivileged user and have run the script (that now contains print statements for debugging). The effective and the real user ID were always identical at every stage of execution. Obviously, **the suid and sgid flags have no effect on scripts.** Thinking about it, this could be expected, because the interpreter itself still runs as me. **So there is no point in making the script suid-root.** I'll try to find other test methods ...

Comment: Crossposted to [PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11157831).